# Localize a float and specify number of decimal places in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, floating-point, nsstring, nslocalizedstring

I have a float that I'd like to display to one decimal place.  E.g. 104.8135674... to be displayed as 104.8 in English.  Usually I'd use:

`myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",myFloat];`

However, I'd like to localize the number, so I tried:

`myString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.1f",myFloat];`

This works to assign the correct decimal symbol (e.g.

English:  104.8

German:  104,8

However, for languages that use don't use [arabic numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals) (0123456789), the correct decimal symbol is used, but the numbers are still in arabic numerals. e.g.

Bahrain-Arabic:  104,8  (it should use different symbols for the numbers)

So I tried:

`myString = [NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat] numberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];`

But with that I can't seem to specify the number of decimal places.  It gives e.g.

English:  104.813

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NSNumberFormatter `-setMaximumFractionDigits:` is used for that purpose and you can reuse the formatter which is quite good:

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter =  [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString * myString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:123.456]];
```

Comment: That's it, I started down that track too, but lost it somewhere along the way.  Thanks for setting me straight.