# ios restrict to input more than one "." or "," (if it is russian localization)

Tags: ios, input, block, restrict

problem is that on russian localization numeric pad has "," instead of "." and when view is loaded i have "0.0" in the text field, when I thought that user would be able to input only "." I used such code to prevent inputting more than one "."

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSArray  *arrayOfString = [newString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];

    if ([arrayOfString count] > 2 )
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

but when occured that in rus localization pad appears with "," instead of "." I can't find out how I can prevent of inputting "," if there is "." already

and i am replacing inputted "," with "." so i will be glad if someone helps to restrict inputting "," if thereis "." in the text field already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSNumberFormatter to have a localized number in your field when it displays.

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter =  [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSString * myString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:123.456]];
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11504127/719866

You can use the formatter in your check to see if the value entered by the user is valid for that locale with the `-numberFromString:` method.